# Ошибка php mysqli_query: Error while sending QUERY packet

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Периодически в логах вываливается

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=36408

в скрипте на mysqli_query:

```
foreach ($aData as $p_id=>$p_ip) {
    $p_req = "SELECT ip FROM base WHERE ip='".$p_ip."'";
    $p_res = mysqli_query($db,$p_req);
    if ($p_res) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($p_res)==0) $p_row[] = $aData[$p_id];
        mysqli_free_result($p_res); 
    }
}
```

Обратился к хостеру. Написали:
добавьте следующую строку, возможно обернув в функцию mysql_query:

```
SET SESSION max_allowed_packet = 256M
```

Добавил

```
mysqli_query($db, ‘SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = ’ . 256*1024*1024 );
```

Не помогло.
Погуглил и добавил еще

```
mysqli_query($db, ‘SET @@global.wait_timeout = ’ . 60 );
```

Все равно Warning вылазит.
Скрипт, то маленький. Цикл не более 2000 раз за запуск. Памяти должно хватать.

Читал, что для `max_allowed_packet` нужно значение длины запроса умноженное на 1024. Длина моего запроса не превышает 50 байт. Запрос за один проход выполняется за 0,0004 сек. База занимает 1,75Мб.
Куда копать? Или хостера дергать?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: вы `aData` откуда берете? не из БД что ли? дергать 2000раз запросы это не нормально для скрипта.

Comment: aData не из БД. 2000 - это сильно с запасом. в среднем от 200 до 500.

Comment: заюзайте подготовленные запросы, их как раз для этих целей используют (множественный вызов одного запроса с разными параметрами). Но в любом случае, даже 200 или 500 запросов в скрипте это дохерищи просто. Пробуйте объединять пачкой, выбирать результат, и потом обрабатывать его, сократив с 200 до 5-10 например. Либо как вариант вставка всего этого одним запросом во временную таблицу, и выборка с джойном. последнее небось самым эффективным окажется по времени работы.

Comment: либо хз как часто ваша data меняется, мб ее можно влить в БД и с некоторой периодичностью там обновлять, например.

Comment: Собственно это и есть часть скрипта по вливанию aData в БД. Скрипт делал пару лет назад под расширение БД. Наверное 1-5 запросами действительно будет и быстрее и лучшее. Спасибо в любом случае. Иногда зашоришься на какой нибудь хрени!

Comment: Проблема решена! По крайней мере в этом случае. Сначала переделал запрос в цикле на 1 запрос с выгрузкой в массив. Но ошибка все равно выскакивала. Присмотревшись осенило. Соединение открывал в начале скрипта, а запрос делал ближе к концу. В промежутке скрипт делал обработку достаточно длительное время, поэтому таймаут был превышен. Перенес коннект перед запросом и вуаля. Может кому поможет моя невнимательность. Еще раз спасибо teran за помощь.