# Ошибка Error while sending QUERY packet. PID= при работе с циклом

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Имеется массив с данными, примерно 10000 элементов (не предел) - пользователи вк  с полями ( `user_id`, `name`, `photo`, `total_score`) получаю через vk api.

Требуется добавить их в базу данных, причем если уже есть в базе данных пользователь с `user_id`  мы обновляем данные  если пользователя не существует то мы его вставляем в бд

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $bdname);
foreach ($user_arr as user) {//over 10k
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM top_users WHERE usd='".$user[id]."' AND date='".$date."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if($data[0]){
        $sql="UPDATE top_users SET total_score='".$user[total_score]."' WHERE usd='".$user[id]."' AND date='".$date."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    }
    else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO top_users (ID,usd,name,img,total_score,date) VALUES  (NULL,'".$user[id]."','".$user[name]."','".$user[photo]."','".$user[total_score]."','".$date."')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    }

}
```

так вот мне  выадет вот такую ошибку

> Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=11076 in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\Config.php on line 38

собственно строка вот   `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);`

Comment: не насилуйте сервер. разбейте весь массив на пачки по скажем 500 строк, вставьте во временную таблицу используя `insert into .. values (....),   (....) ....`, потом из временной напишите один запрос а вставку-апдейт в основную. не надо для этой задачи выполнять 20+ тысяч запросов к БД

Comment: и еще на тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759656/223826